# JVM Crash - Windows 10 - Need help to understand the log file

Tags: netbeans, jvm, windows-10, logfile, jvm-crash

I upgraded my SO to Windows 10 few weeks ago.

After this my jvm keep crashing when im on netbeans.

[**Crash Log**](http://pastebin.com/CeXsVf9u)

*Need some guidance.*

Comment: This is a crash in the JDK itself. I suggest you try upgrading both Java and  ensure you have the latest windows updates.

Comment: I already have the latest version from both :/

Comment: It appears you have Java 8 update 101, you can get update 111 and 112.

Answer (score 0):

The crash was related to my motherboard video output.

I'm using 3 monitors (2x vga 1x moba), when i use the motherboard monitor with netbeans i got the error.

Maybe some issue with my display driver ?